# Java MongoDB getting value for sub document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to get the value of a key from a sub-document and I can't seem to figure out how to use the BasicDBObject.get() function since the key is embedded two levels deep. Here is the structure of the document

```
File { 
  name: file_1
    report: {
      name: report_1,
      group: RnD
    }
}
```

Basically a file has multiple reports and I need to retrieve the names of all reports in a given file. I am able to do `BasicDBObject.get("name")` and I can get the value "file_1", but how do I do something like this `BasicDBObject.get("report.name")`? I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: When you say it did not work what actually happened?

Comment: When it didnt work, it returned nothing.

Answer (score 11):

You should first get the "report" object and then access its contents.You can see the sample code in the below.

```
DBCursor cur = coll.find();

for (DBObject doc : cur) {
    String fileName = (String) doc.get("name");
    System.out.println(fileName);

    DBObject report = (BasicDBObject) doc.get("report");
    String reportName = (String) report.get("name");
    System.out.println(reportName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a second way of doing it, on another post (didnt save the link otherwise I would have included that).

```
(BasicDBObject)(query.get("report")).getString("name")
```

where query = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next()

Comment: This is the same as i wrote.Instead of two line they wrote query in single line.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use queries, as in the case of MongoTemplate and so on...

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("report.name").is("some value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this worked for me

`BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("report.name", "some value");`

Comment: For querying fields in subdocuments, using this dot notation worked perfectly for me.  Thanks.